# Data structure for activity feed

Tags: data-structures, database-design, sharepoint-2013, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

There's a concept of a workspace in our application. A user can be a member of virtually any number of workspaces and a workspace can have virtually any number of users. I want to implement an activity feed to help users find out what happened in every workspace they're members of, i.e. when someone uploads a file or creates a task in a workspace, this activity appears in that workspace's activity feed and also in each of its users activity feeds. The problem is that I can't come up with a suitable data structure for quick read and write operations of activities. What I have come up with is storing each activity with a property `Targets` which is a string of all the workspace's user ids and then filtering activities where that field contains an id of a user I want to fetch activities for, but this approach has serious performance and scalability limitations, because we use SharePoint as our storage. We can also use Azure Table or Blob Storage and I was thinking of just creating a separate activity entity for every user of a workspace so that then I can just easily filter activities by user's id, but this could result in hundreds of copies of the same activity if a workspace has hundreds of members and then writing all those copies becomes problematic as Azure only supports 100 entities in a single batch operation (correct me if I'm wrong), and SharePoint then is not an option at all. So I need help figuring out what data structure I could use to store activities of each workspace so that they're easily retrievable for any member probably by its id and also for any workspace by workspace's id.

Answer (score 1):

> We can also use Azure Table or Blob Storage and I was thinking of just creating a separate activity entity for every user of a workspace so that then I can just easily filter activities by user's id

Azure Storage Table could be a choice for storing your activity entities, and Table storage is relatively inexpensive, you can consider storing the same entity multiple times (with different partitioning strategy) in separate partitions or in separate tables for reading efficient.

And storing user’s activity entity with `workspaceid_userid` as a compound key can be also a possible approach. For more and detailed Table design patterns, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide#table-design-patterns).

> Azure only supports 100 entities in a single batch operation (correct me if I'm wrong)

Yes, a single [batch operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#insert-a-batch-of-entities) can include up to 100 entities.

Comment: But if a workspace can have virtually any number of members, i.e. 1000 (although I doubt this is ever gonna happen, but still), isn't it dumb to insert 1000 identical entities with different `RowKey`s, which would also require to do 10 separate batch requests? I'm not saying that it is, but I'm asking, because I only have experience with relational (mostly SQL) databases where this approach would be considered insane.

Comment: Every time a user's activity entity need to be saved, if using the first approach, you may need to store the activity entity for two times (storing it with ``userid`` as PartitionKey and store same activity entity with ``workspaceid`` as PartitionKey).

Comment: And then how I get activities from all workspaces that user is a member of with a single query? I mean a user can be a member of, let's say, 10 worskspaces. Other users in those workspaces posts some activities. I store each acitivity twice with `userId` and `workspaceId` as `PartitionKey`s. Then how I retrieve all those activities from those 10 workspaces with a single query?